# New database, but record still shows 1 record with all null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, `Project` and `ProjectImage`. These two are associated.

Why is it that if I haven't uploaded any photos yet, there's already a record in my `ProjectImage` but all the values are null's? I cleaned out my database with `rake db:create db:migrate`

I'm confused...

```
<%= @project.project_images.to_json %>
```

Gives me

```
 [{"id":null,
   "project_id":null,
   "project_photo_id":null,
   "file_id":null,
   "created_at":null,
   "updated_at":null,
   "photo_file_name":null,
   "photo_content_type":null,
   "photo_file_size":null,
   "photo_updated_at":null}]
```

I'm using paperclip gem

## EDIT

```
<%= simple_form_for @project, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
 <%= file_field_tag "photos[]", multiple: true %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.project_images.build
  end
end
```

Do you think its coming form the `@project.project_images.build`?

Comment: are you building or initializing the project_images somewhere in action before coming to the view.?

Comment: Can you include the code for the controller action?

Comment: I believe I'm initializing. This is in a form where I was trying to create a project, and wanted to do an if statement to make sure that there are no images associated to this "new" project

Comment: if you want only persisted records do this `<%= @project.project_images.select(&:persisted?).to_json %>`  i hope my syntax is correct

Comment: @eirikir which method should i show?

Comment: @Athar well I'm just showing a json only because, I wanted to do a check to make sure that if the array of photos is empty, but its not, which it should be because I've never uploaded any photos

Comment: What does `@project.project_images.count` give you?

Comment: @hellomello The action code that's being executed prior to the `to_json` line. A `project_image` is being built but not saved at some point, and to find it, we need to see the code.

Comment: okay @hellomello i updated my comment as well. when you intialize some assosiation against some object it gets assosiated to it that is why when you do `<%= @project.project_images.to_json %>` this also shows initialize objects as well.  `<%= @project.project_images.select(&:persisted?).to_json %>` this will help you fetch only those records  of project_images which only exists in the database

Comment: `<%= @project.project_images.select(&:persisted?).count %>` will give you the count of the project_images exist for that project. and if this count is 0 then you should create a new one.

Comment: Just post the controller and complete form

Comment: @lurker weird, I get a count of 0, if I do that

Comment: @Athar that makes sense. When I do `.select(&:persisted?)` I just get an empty array `[]` which I think this is supposed to happen. So then now, I can check if .empty? right?

Comment: @hellomello yes if you want to just confirm that is there any project_images are there for project yes you  can add .empty? at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EDIT identifies the issue: `@project.project_images.build`  creates a new, unsaved ProjectImage and pushes it into the `@project.project_images` relation (see the definition of [ActiveRelation#build](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-build)). So, when your view renders that relation, it includes the empty record. Don't worry, it's not actually in your database! You can tell that the image isn't saved because of how its `id` column isn't null (or use the `persisted?` method like [Athar mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641355/new-database-but-record-still-shows-1-record-with-all-null#comment51229443_31641355)).

To fix this, you can just remove the `@project.project_images.build` line from your controller. It doesn't seem to serve a purpose.